# Reading DWG files in R?

Tags: r, shapefile, dwg

Is there any way to open a DWG file in R and save it as an ESRI shapefile?
I don't know any package available yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the rgdal package which is a port to [GDAL](https://gdal.org/). To access the OGR functionality that supports vector topology you want the readORG and writeOGR functions. Here is a list of vector formats supported by [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/index.html)